# Disabling built-in indexes in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm currently doing a benchmark to see if Google Cloud Datastore could suit our needs but I've got a problem with how indexes are handled.
I know that I will never have to filter on anything except the key field, and thus I would like to be able to disable the built-in indexing of all the other fields. I just want to use it as a key/value store.

I'm currently looking at potentially multiple TB of indexes if I cannot disable them (~50 fields, billions of rows) and that would kill our budget.

Is there any way to remove these indexes ? It seems the *index.yaml* file this [link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig?hl=en) talks about is only about composite indexes.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it ! You can explicitly tell Datastore not to index your field by doing it like [this](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#unindexed_properties) (excluded properties)

Answer (score 0):

I have researched in [Datastore github issues](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/83) about this same question, about (2015), the last inquiry was on 2019. But there is no response. You can ask there if it has been any

I have also researched in the Public Issue Tracker [PIT](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) of Google Cloud Platform for an existing Feature Request (FR) or Issue related with this, but not found any.

I think the best way to proceed is to file a FR with the [proper components](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187197&template=0). In this way the Engineering team will have visibility about this. The PIT uses the number of "stars" (people who have indicated interest in an issue) to prioritize work on the platform. Given that there is no FR opened, you should open a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I replied to the GitHub issue and I'll wait for other answers in this thread, maybe someone from the GCP team will come by !